# how to parse float in javascript like c# float?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am newbie to javascript, forgive me if i ask this kind of question

in c# I have :

(float)3772/32767 = 0.1151158**21**

but in javascript i have :

3772/32767 = 0.1151158**1774346141**

I heard there is a function parseFloat but it does not fix my problem

I want the result to be like the c# float result, because in javascript side it brings some noise to my final data, how to cast like a c# float ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) or [`toPrecision()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision) methods to change the precision of float-numbers:

```js
let number = 3772/32767;

console.log(number);

console.log(number.toFixed(7));

console.log(number.toPrecision(8));
```

Comment: Yes but I also want the last two digits

Comment: No matter what significance you round to it'll never be `0.115115821`, since `17` is either rounded to `2` or `177` is rounded to `18`

Comment: yes I agree, this was just an example, i have thousands of operations , each operation needs its own precision

Comment: And since floating point math is very different between c# and js you're unlikely to get the same number when you're talking about billionths